# How to prevent character from tunneling through walls in unreal engine?

Tags: graphics, game-engine, game-development, unreal-engine5

I am a beginner for unreal and I am making a game and I got to know that unknowingly I messed something so my character is able to tunnel walls.
[image]

Here are my Viewport settings
[image]

What am I supposed to do (to make it normal as it was in the beginning when I played for first time)?

Comment: Would you please stop spamming tags? E.g. what has this question to do with `basic`?

Comment: I'm about to remove the basic tag for him.  I remove on average two basic tags a day, probably the most mis-used tag ever.